# Ajax not working on phonegap

Tags: android, ajax, api, cordova, cors

I am making native application from phonegap.

first of all i had make rest api in mvc and my all functions return json behavior and allow get.

then i have make one html file like index.html then this file run in firefox and getting error like third party cross domain error and this error i have fixed make some code in my web.config and **now working fine my ajax code in browsers**

then this html page i am simple copy paste in eclips and run my application in emulator and looking fine but **my ajax call always error**.

and i am follow step like:

1) `<access origin="*" /><access origin="http://www.testsite.com:8090/Controller/Actionname" />` in config.xml file

2) `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in androidMenifest.xml file

**but still ajax fail**

Html code look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Unable to zooming device-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" ></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<section id="login">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-wrap">
                <h1>Log in with your email account</h1>
                  <!--  <form role="form" action="javascript:;" method="post" id="login-form" autocomplete="off">-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="somebody@example.com">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="key" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="key" id="key" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <input type="button" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg btn-block" value="Log in">
                    <!--</form>-->
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="forget" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".forget-modal">Forgot your password?</a>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- /.col-xs-12 -->
        </div> <!-- /.row -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</section>


</body>

</html>
```

Ajax code look like:

```
<script charset="utf&minus;8" type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn-login").click(function(){
var email = $("#email").val();
var pwd = $("#key").val();
var URL = "http://www.testsite.com:8090/Controller/ActionName?email=abc@abc.com&password=123123&apiToken=45retw54fgw45fgq345fg"; //iis url
var URL1 = "http://localhost:15536/Controller/ActionName?email=abc@abc.com&password=123123&apiToken=45retw54fgw45fgq345fg";

             $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                type:"POST",
                datatype:"json",
                success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.data);
                window.location.href="welcome.html";
                },
                error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
                }
            });

});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Try putting a log/alert before your ajax call to makes ure your click event is handled properly with email and pwd. By the way you should use deviceready event to make sure cordova is ready (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)

Comment: I am sure my ajax call is working because i am getting this two alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); after click on button

Comment: why don't you share the errors then?

Comment: because i am not getting proper error in alert. see my first alert display "0" and second is empty and i think not able to check console log when page in phonegap.

Comment: you can check console log with phonegap using console plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The zero you are getting is your server response code.  Your request is getting blocked as a cross domain request.  Your desktop browsers allow this but phonegap doesn't.  Try using jsonp and a ajax get request to solve this cross domain rejection.. 
Modify this to suit your needs and modify your script to take a get input:
`$.ajax({timeout: 5000,
        url: 'http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        callback: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'yourcallback',
        type: "GET",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {'scriptinput':'data string you send'}
    });
    function yourcallback(response) {
       console.log(response);
    }`

Be sure to wrap your response as a json string in a function call `yourcallback(yourjsonstring)`.
Here's an example of how this works for me on the server side in PHP.  Hopefully you can get an idea how to modify your iis server side script from this.

```
function SendAnswer($response)  {
    // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    }
    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS");         

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    }
    header("content-type: application/json");
    $callback = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'callback', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    echo  "$callback(" . json_encode($response) . ")";
}
```

Best of luck to you.